# VB Razor Syntax for multi line helper

Tags: vb.net, razor, kendo-ui

In Kendo UI, there are lots of fluent helpers which are easiest to use in multi-line syntax.  In C#, you can do that easily by adding a `@(` before and `)` after the code.

Is there an equivalent in VB?

```
@Html.Kendo().TabStrip() _
    .Name("tabstrip") this line is normal text, not VB
```

I found that you can use `.Render()` at the end of a `@Code` block, but I would rather use the multi-line syntax if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@(` and `)` exactly like you would in C#.  The problem was the text editor in VS 2010 does not handle line breaks very well with Razor.  A couple of things to watch out for:

- The `_` line continuation character will be automatically removed if there's no text on the next line
- If more `(`'s than `)`'s, you're text will show up as text until them all
- Automatic completion does not function as long as the text editor thinks your in text not code.  So `Sub(x)` will not get a `End Sub` always.